# Setting Canvas.Zindex value in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In my WP 8.1 app I have the MapControl:

```
            <Maps:MapControl x:Name="mapControl" ZoomLevelChanged="mapControl_ZoomLevelChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapIcons" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                    <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Tapped="myStack_Tapped" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding GeoPoint}" Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding Anchor}">
                                <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Background="White" Height="150" Width="220" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Image x:Name="myImage" Source="{Binding MapMarker}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl>
            </Maps:MapControl>
```

On the map I got markers, and when I click one of them, "contentGrid" apears. The code for that behavior:

```
private void myStack_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel s = sender as StackPanel;
        Grid contentBox = s.FindName("contentGrid") as Grid;
        contentBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

I want to see "contentGrid" always above other markers, but some of them are above my "contentGrid". I tried to set Canvas.Zindex property in XAML in "contentGrid", but it's not working.

[I attach screenshot to exemplify my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB8mf.png)

Comment: If you want to see the contentGrid above other markers, setting ZIndex won't help, because it would only by relative to the Panel in the DataTemplate, but not to the MapItemsControl's ItemsPanel. You may either set ZIndex in an ItemContainerStyle, or you put a second MapItemsControl with the contentGrids on top of the first one.

Comment: @Clemens I created two MapItemsControl according to your suggestion and it works perfectly. Thanks man, you are great :)

Answer (score 0):

The `StackPanel` stacks vertically (by default) or horizontally.

If you want children of the StackPanel in "different layers", 
you 'd better replace the `StackPanel` of the `DataTemplate` with a `Grid` or `Canvas`

A simple solution is to

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Grid Tapped="myStack_Tapped" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding GeoPoint}" Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding Anchor}">
    <Image x:Name="myImage" Source="{Binding MapMarker}"/>        
    <Grid x:Name="contentGrid" Background="White" Height="150" Width="220" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Writing the Image in the XAML before the Grid puts it under graphically.

Last, you can play with the ZIndex if you add other controls are added to the Grid/Canvas.

Otherwise I am not sure the ZIndex is really necessaray

**EDIT**

`Canvas.ZIndex` is an attached property of Canvas.

But surprisingly it works with the Grid !

The greater Zindex is, the closer the control to your eye (over the other controls)

Regards

Comment: Unfortunetely it's not working with that code. Still when I tap on one of marker, the "contentGrid" is under markers. I tried to add ZIndex to "contentGrid", but it's now working for some reason.

Comment: @Druy, you replaced the StackPanel, direct child of the DataTemplate, right ? I tested in a solution without BingMaps, and it works as I expected. Of course, you have to edit the code of the tapped callback to take into account it is a grid, no more a stackpanel.

Comment: Yes, I did everything like in your answer, but now i got something like this: http://oi63.tinypic.com/xmtnww.jpg As you can see, clicked marker disappeared under Grid, and some of markers are still above the Grid.